# DateTime format in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to execute the following query in SQL Server 2005.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [WAGON_LOADING].[dbo].[WEIGHT_DATA]
WHERE [DATEANDTIME] BETWEEN '2013-11-7 0:00:00.000' AND '2013-11-7 23:59:59.000'
```

The query's syntax is OK. But when I execute the query, it is showing no output (the database has got only today's data i.e, 7th November), but when I change the date time in the query to 
`2013-7-11 0:00:00.000` AND `2013-7-11 23:59:59.000` I am getting all the values.

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never rely on implicit conversions from string to date (or on any implicit converison, for that matter). Use a conversion method and specify a format.

Comment: Note that `YYYYMMDD` and `YYYY-MM-DD` are both language neutral and not affected by the `SET DATEFORMAT` and `SET LANGUAGE` settings. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.  YYYYMMDD is the most reliable string date format on SQL Server.

```
SELECT * FROM [WAGON_LOADING].[dbo].[WEIGHT_DATA] 
WHERE [DATEANDTIME] >= '20131107' AND [DATEANDTIME] < '20131108'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SQL Server is parsing your dates out of order. You can configure this using [`SET DATEFORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) with one of the [numeric date format values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189622%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

The default for your server is specified by the `[dateformat]` column in the row of [`sys.syslanguages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190303%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) corresponding to your current [language setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM PURCHASE 
WHERE OrderDate >='2004-03-01  00:00:00.000' AND OrderDate < '2004-04-01  00:00:00.000'
```